# Set customer group from customer registration form

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I was trying to let the customer choose the customer group while the customer registration in magento 2.

What i did was, i passed the group id on hidden field like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="group_id" id="group_id" value="2" />
```

But it is not working. When i check the customer from admin panel, the default group was chosen.

My question is:

1. Can I change the customer group this way?
2. I can see another method of using event observer method on customer register success but I would prefer this method if it works?

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks

Comment: The solution you are suggesting is for magento 1 but i am asking for magento 2. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: try : $this->session->setCustomerGroupId("2");

Comment: Where should i add above snippet??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I get to solve it so i thought answering here so that it would help others too.

**What I did?**

I choose event-observer approach to get this done. I created a module which track the customer register success event.You can create the module on the fly from https://mage2gen.com/ . This is very cool and it let's to create a module easily. I just created an observer with the event **customer_register_success** and it gives me the whole module.

It provide with the observer, with just class and few things defined.

Below is the code added by me:

```
<?php 


namespace Custom\Customergroup\Observer\Customer;
// added by me
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;




class RegisterSuccess implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {

/**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
//added by me
    private $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
         CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
        )
    {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }
    //ends here
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ){      

        $id = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer()->getId();
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($id);

         $group_id = $this->_request->getParam('group_id');

        $customer->setGroupId($group_id);

        $this->customerRepository->save($customer);

    }
}
```

I have added the comment which shows my modification.

If anyone has better solution please feel free to add.

Regards

Comment: have you added your code in that module in observer folder

Comment: can you tell me in brief with path of your extension

Comment: check the name space to get the path of the file name

Comment: I have tested it and looks like all fine only the customer load because it is giving error that no customer exists with the id, So one thing I assume is you already have customer data from which you are getting id, So there is no need to load the customer again. But +10 for the great idea of creating extension on the fly, it helps me a lot. Thank you

Comment: Sorry for the selfless promotion but there is ready made extension that does this and much more - http://bit.ly/M2-Customer-Group-Switcher-Pro-Fb

Comment: @MagePsycho nice extension

Answer (score 3):

First create your configuration file in [Company Name][Module Name]\etc\frontend\events.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer instance="[Company Name]\[Module Name]\Observer\Frontend\Customer\RegisterSuccess" name="[Company Name]_[Module Name]_observer_frontend_customer_registersuccess_customer_register_success"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Then create the observer:

```
<?php


namespace [Company Name]\[Module Name]\Observer\Frontend\Customer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class RegisterSuccess implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

     const CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID = 2;

      protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;

      public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
    ) {
        $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    }

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
       $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        if ($customer->getGroupId() == 1) {
            $customer->setGroupId(self::CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID);
            $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->save($customer);;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: working 100% thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pls check this link

Magento2 Customer Group Change in a custom registration form #2650

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2650

Comment: Thanks pratik, i had already visited that but it's not much of help.

Comment: it's working for my end.