# Add customer to group when registering

Tags: customer, magento-2.1, customer-account, customer-group

I'm not sure how to programmatically add customer to one of previously created customer groups when he/she registers.

There are 2 groups:

1. General customer - basic group
2. Regular customer - customer needs to be added there if he/she requests a *regular customer card*

I need to add a customer to the latter group programmatically. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is two way to achieve this functionality :

1. Call the event `customer_register_success` and change the user group just after registration.

Follow this solution : [Set customer group from customer registration form](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141737/set-customer-group-from-customer-registration-form/141839)

2. Create a stand alone page where you have to get customer collection according to your  filter condition and set the new user group and save the customer.

Comment: This link correspond to the Magento 1 but question is about the Magento 2

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau, check updated answer